# Regular expression to match string that has four or more words?

Tags: html, regex

I need to validate HTML form input to have at least 4 words in a text input. For example, "A B C D" would match but "A B C" would not.

I have have tried breaking this down into matching a string that has 3 or more single spaces anywhere throughout but am new to regex as of today. I've played around with variations of `/^ {3,}+$/`, but understand that this is just matching three space characters repeated in a row. I've been hacking at this for a few hours now so I can't quite remember everything else that I've attempted. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `pattern="\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){3,}\s*"`. If you by words you mean ASCII letters try `pattern="[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]+(?:[^A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+){3,}[^A-Za-z]*"`

Comment: Did my solution above work or did any of the solutions below work for you? Please provide feedback.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\w+(?: \w+){3,}$
```

Using `\s` is not recommend , because it includes [ \t\r\n\f]. That is: \s matches a space, a tab, a carriage return, a line feed, or a form feed.

**Explanation** `\w+` checking for the first word. (That word can contain [a-zA-Z_].  `( \w+){3,}` checking for next 3 or more words (a word must be started with a space and have one or more word charactors).

Answer (score 1):

It's not fancy (still newish to writing these) but it works:

```
\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+([\s\w+]\w+)?
```

Matches any number of word characters followed by a space 3 times or more and ending with a word character.

Answer (score 1):

If your words are separated by spaces, you can just [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on that and count the number of results, passing if it is 4 or more. Note we [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the string first so that leading or trailing spaces don't erroneously increase the word count:

```js
let str = 'A B C D';

if (str.trim().split(' ').length >= 4)
  console.log("'" + str + "' is OK");

str = 'A B C ';

if (str.trim().split(' ').length >= 4)
  console.log("'" + str + "' is OK");
```